# how to use autocomplete search places in googlemap

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to add autocomplete search box to the top of googlemap ,so i can write place and it complete it for me then move camera to this place ..
How can I do it?
[image]

Comment: There is an API for google which you can use:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

Comment: Check this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/

You need to add Google place to your project and use their 'place autocomplete' as mentioned here:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete

Good luck.